# How do I scroll an internal scroll bar using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape data off a website using Selenium in Python, where the data only appears once I click a 'Details' button, the problem is that this button isn't initially visible and requires scrolling on an internal scroll bar
[(circled in red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1JiK.png)

For reference, here's the website:
https://www.abt-sportsline.com/tuning/configurator#80706385!43C6B47

The goal is to scroll this internal scroll bar so I can click the button and view/scrape the data.

Here's my initial code:

```
scrollBar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="mCSB_1_dragger_vertical"]/div')
driver.execute_script("arguments.scrollBy(0,arguments[0].scrollHeight)", scrollBar)
temp_element = in_tab_object.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div > div > div > div.row > div.col-xs-12.product-details > div > div.text-right.details-link > span.icon-ArrowRight")
temp_element.click()
```

This does not scroll the internal bar at all and I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

I have another idea of solving this problem, where I find the scrollbar container and click the bottom of it, hence, scrolling all the way down, but I am unsure how to specify clicking local coordinates of a container.

Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: You'll probably need to select the frame which has the scroll bar first and then start scrolling on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try ActionChains.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as AC

dr = webdriver.Chrome("[path_to_your_chromedriver]")

dr.get("https://www.abt-sportsline.com/tuning/configurator#80713308!5972E27")

aa = dr.find_element_by_id("mCSB_1_scrollbar_vertical")

action = AC(dr)

action.click_and_hold(aa).move_by_offset(0,1).perform()

# Don't forget to release the click_and_hold, for example with:

action.reset_actions()
```

This does not work very well, however. I think it's something to do with that it is a custom scroll bar.

Read more about action chains here:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains

.

Comment: Thanks! While this probably isn't the best solution, it worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

As it is not inside frame, You can easily use `scrolled_once_into_view` which is the same as scrollIntoView() in js.

for instance:

```py
element = driver.find_element('xpath', "DETAILS_BUTTON_XPATH")
element.scrolled_once_into_view  # Ignore IDE errors for this command. It is working well.
```

Alternatively you can use following (using JS command):

```
element = driver.find_element('xpath', "DETAILS_BUTTON_XPATH")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

Comment: Hey Mohammad, appreciate the response however I am getting the following error for both methods:

AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'execute_script'

Same error with the first method but obviously the attribute is 'scrolled_once_into_view"

Comment: ` 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'execute_script'` shows that you're passing once_scrolled_into_view the driver object. You should pass it to the element object. 
Could you share your code you've written based on my answer?

Comment: `scrollBar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="bmf-tc"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]')`
 `scrollBar.scrolled_once_into_view`